# import/attach some mysql databases

Tags: mysql

I have a directory that looks like:

ar_wiki_latest  ibdata1      ib_logfile1     ko_wiki_latest  ps_wiki_20100302  ru_wiki_latest  zh_wiki_latest
en_wiki_latest  ib_logfile0  ja_wiki_latest  mysql       ps_wiki_latest    test

left over from a decommissioned server. Is there a way to persuade mysql to adopt some of these databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reliable way to do this is to *temporarily* replace your `mysql` data directory with the one you want to import. Start up the mysql server and do a `mysqldump` of the tables you want to import (note you'll be using your *old* mysql login). Shut down MySQL again, replace the temporary, old data dir with your current one, restart MySQL, and then use the mysql command-line tool to import the dump file.

If the database you want to import **only** uses MyISAM, then you can usually just copy the database's directory (e.g. "`en_wiki_latest`") into your new mysql data dir, and it will "just work". However, if the database uses InnoDB, then using this method will cause a disaster. So, to be on the safe side, I'd recommend the method mentioned above.

A quick recap on how to import/export:

**Export:**

```
mysqldump -uUSER -pPASSWORD database_name > database_name.sql
```

**Import:**

```
mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD <<< "create database database_name"
mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD database_name < database_name.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, except for one addition.

Never modify a running system/configuration to do testing or development. Always test and develop on another system or an alternate server or instance. You can run many instances of the same server or many versions of MySQL on the same machine.

Start another instance of MySQL on an alternate port and the alternate data dir. Now you can dump and import while both servers or instances are running.

Excerpt from the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-unix-servers.html

> You need not compile a new MySQL
>   server just to start with a different
>   Unix socket file and TCP/IP port
>   number. It is also possible to use the
>   same server binary and start each
>   invocation of it with different
>   parameter values at runtime. One way
>   to do so is by using command-line
>   options:
>
> shell> mysqld_safe --socket=file_name
>   --port=port_number
>
> To start a second server, provide
>   different --socket and --port option
>   values, and pass a --datadir=path
>   option to mysqld_safe so that the
>   server uses a different data
>   directory.

Same idea for windows, see the manual for syntax.

When making changes for performance or to fix "bugs", prove/test the changes on another server/instance before final testing on a running/production server. This applies to configuration, indices, field types, constraints, procedures, etc..